# Sharepoint 2013 Resource files location

Tags: 2013, resource-files, multilingual

[image]

I'm trying to translate some resource files of sharepoint 2013.
I can't find the messages on the DeltaPageStatusBar when you start to modify the page
For example the resource file for this mesages:

*Checked out to you*

*Only you can see your recent changes*

Or even the watermark at the search box:

*Search this site*

Does anyone know where to find them?

I searched with Find function of VS2012 in:

C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\\App_GlobalResources

C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\Resources

Comment: Why don't you use language packs?

Comment: I use them but, there is no language pack for Albania, and I use the Italian one. So I ended up translating some Italian resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SharePoint 2013 many (most?) of those strings are available either directly in JavaScript files (localized in folders such as Layouts\1033), or in culture-specific resource DLLs. Many of these DLLs are then loaded through the [ScriptResx.ashx](http://www.mavention.nl/blog/globalizing-javascript-sharepoint-2013) handler.

For example, see these objects in JavaScript:

- SP.Res.* -> Loaded through ScriptResx.ashx
- Srch.Res.* -> Lazy loaded through ScriptResx.ashx (by search.clientcontrol.js)
- Strings.*.* -> Loaded directly as 1033\Strings.js
- SP.Publishing.Resources.* -> Lazy loaded through ScriptResx.ashx
- Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.ScriptResources.* -> Lazy loaded through ScriptResx.ashx

More specifically for your examples:

- "Checked out to" == DLL resource (PageStatusHeaderCheckedOutToCurrentUser) in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Intl
- "Publication Start Date" == (IIS folders)\App_GlobalResources\cms.resx key statusindicator_publicationstartdate_label

As a developer living in a bilingual city I hunt for them quite often :). It is unfortunate that there seems to be no standard nomenclature or location, but I am not working with SharePoint for its API homogeneity!

Comment: Hey Luis, I tried all the above files. I opened every javascript file that use the ScriptResx.ashx handler. I found the sb_SitePrompt:'Search This Site...' but it's not the same as "Search this site". I found the "Checked out to" and translated it and saved it. It is not reflected on the site. I'll try to update the question with a screen shoot of what I'm searching to translate.

Comment: The ScriptResx handler loads DLL files and exposes them as JS strings. If you want to translate that, or any string inside a DLL, you would need to recompile the DLL itself.

Comment: I didn't realize you were trying to edit the language pack itself, I thought you wanted to find translations to use. Sorry it was late :). I edited my post to include the true origin of those strings

Comment: :) That was GREAT

Comment: Let me know if you can't find the others